# parallel.foreach pass multiple variables to function

Tags: vb.net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have the following code that reads multiple CSV files and then passes the data to a class using threads. I have to pass the CSV path and a string to the function (both of which have to be dynamic).

```
    Dim MyThread1 As PassResourceDataToClassDelagate = AddressOf PassResourceDataToClass
    Dim FileTypes() As String = {".HOURLY", ".INTERVAL", ".EDSOLUTION", ".MCECTRL", ".PNODE"}
    Dim TextBoxValues() As String = {RTBMHourlyTextBox.Text, RTBMIntervalTextBox.Text, _
                                    RTBMEDSolutionTextBox.Text, RTBMMCECTRLTextBox.Text, _
                                    RTBMPNodeTextBox.Text}
    For K As Integer = 0 To 4
        MyThread1.BeginInvoke(DirectCast(ReadCSVFile(TextBoxValues(K)), Object()()), FileTypes(K), Nothing, Nothing)
    Next
```

I'm trying to learn Parallel.ForEach to do the same thing. Searching the internet has got me this (which does not work):

```
    Parallel.ForEach(TextBoxValues, FileTypes, Sub(ByRef TBName As String, ByRef FleType As String) _
                                                PassResourceDataToClass(DirectCast(ReadCSVFile(TBName), _
                                                                        Object()()), FleType))
```

Anybody got a better idea?

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What *does* it do?

Comment: The threading code is a nested function call. The inner function passes a file path and returns an object. The outer function takes the object, and populates a class. The thread works, but I was just trying to "build my toolbox" and learn how to convert the thread code to the parallel.foreach code. I guess I don't know how to pass 2 variables to the nested function.